# How does C executes its IF statement?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

There is no `boolean` type in C programming language, but then how does the C language turn's `IF/Else` to true and false?

What is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler does not convert the conditional expression to a boolean value before it decides which branch of the `if`/`else` statement should be taken. Instead it generates assembler instructions just like you would have written if you would have written the program in assembler.

A simple example:

```
if (x > y)
{
   // Do something
}
else
{
   // Do something else
}
```

Could be translated into (using a fictitious microcontroller):

```
    CMP R12,R13
    BLE label1
    // Do something
    JMP label2
label1:
    // Do something else
label2:
```

If the condition is even simpler, as in:

```
if (x)
```

The C language will consider `x` to be *true* if it is non-zero and *false* otherwise.

If the condition contains `||` and/or `&&` operators, the compiler will generate code that short-circuits the test. In other words, for the expression `x != 0 && a/x == y`, the second test will not even be performed if the first test is not true. In this case, this is utilized to ensure that a division by zero is not performed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *true* and *false* for a CPU : only `0` and `1`.

Basically, in C :

- Something that is false is equal to 0 -- which a CPU can test
- And something that is true is not equal to 0 -- which is also something a CPU can test.

Answer (score 1):

for conditionals, a nonzero value is equivalent to true, and a zero value is equivalent to false.